# Old mysqlite.db file copied in simulator folder even though I deleted it ios

Tags: ios, xcode, file, sqlite, copy

This is weird. I have an xcode project with a sqlite file (mysqlite.db)
I updated this file in xcode but when I use the simulator the old version shows up.
I deleted the whole simulator folder, still when I launch the simulator
the old file appears.
I even cancelled the file and renamed it. The old file (with the old name) is still there 
, in myapp.app ,
even if it's absent from the computer.

It must be cached somewhere but where?

Have you got any idea?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your project? Xcode > Project > Clean.

If this doesn't work, consider deleting the app from the simulator, clean and then run it again.

Comment: Many thanks! I cleaned and deleted the app from the simulator and now it's all right.